# Retaining a entry with mex value from multiple entries using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have tab delim text file as follows:

```
A1 230 12 250
A1 100 20 135
A1 90 15 210
A2 150 23 300
B2 300 14 350
B2 190 34 200
B3 210 4 273
B3 100 0 123
C1 110 7 132
C1 98  3 132
C1 101 0 150
D1 301 12 230
D1 660 20 700
D1 275 12 700
```

All I want is to generate a 4th column with values obtained from by dividing the Second column($2)/Fourth Column($4) and retain only those entries which has maximum value in 4th column for the multiple entries and print the file like follows:

```
A1 230 12 250
A2 150 23 300
B2 190 34 200
B3 100 0 123
C1 110 7 132
C1 101 0 150
D1 301 12 230
D1 660 20 700
```

I tried the following command

```
awk '{$5=($2/$4)*100}' myfile.txt |sort|uniq
```

but it failed and didnt gave my desired output. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note `awk '{$5=($2/$4)*100}' ` is not going to print anything. You at least need to say `awk '{ ... } 1' file` to get the line printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the file is pre sorted by `$1`:

```
awk '
# Print the max record when we encounter a different $1
FNR != 1 && prev != $1 {
  print maxRecord;
  # Set variables
  prev = $1;
  maxCalc = 0;
}
{
  # Find the max between calc and maxCalc
  calc = ($2/$4)*100;
  if (calc > maxCalc) { 
    maxRecord = $0;
    maxCalc = calc;
  }
}
END{print maxRecord}' file
```

This will not set the fifth record (the calculation), but if you want that you can simple add the following before `maxRecord = $0`:

```
$5 = calc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but how can retain the entry which is maximum value in $5 for multiple entries?

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl instead of awk:

```
< myfile.txt perl -ape 's%$%" " . $F[1]/$F[3]%e' \
| sort -k1,1 -k5,5nr \
| sort -k1,1 -u
```

Perl just adds the new column. The first sort then sorts by category and by the new column, the second sort only keeps the first line for each category.